# Can multiple relationship occur between two entities?

Tags: sql, erd

[image]

I have following two entities, where a person address is kept in a separate table because a person can have multiple addresses.
The mailing address however is one of the multiple addresses stored in address table, which is to be referred in person table.
Can following relationship exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is "Yes".  However, you cannot *declare* the model only using `create table` because:

- Declaring the foreign key `address.person_id` requires that the `person` table already exist.
- Declaring the foreign key `person.mailing_address` requires that the `address` table already exist.

Hence, to implement the model, you need to use `alter table` to add one or both of the constraints after both tables are created.

Is this the model you want?  One feature of an address is that multiple people can have the same address.  Your model does not allow that.  To handle this, you would typically have *three* tables:

- `Person`
- `Address`
- `PersonAddress`

The third table has one row for each person/address pair.  It can also have other information such as:

- Type ("mailing" versus other types)
- Effective and end dates.
- Perhaps other information.

If you want to guarantee uniqueness of the "mailing" address in such a model, many databases support filtered unique indexes, to ensure there are no duplicate mailing addresses.

Comment: As much as stackoverflow hates assignment solutions, this is the exact scenario stated by the question: The proposed College database should be able to keep track of all people. For each person, it records all his / her address, of which exactly one is designated as the mailing address. Else, I would not have separated it. Thank you so much for such a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have person_id as an fk on address but that doesn't look correct. There are lots of correct ways to model this and the best one for you will depend on you particular circumstances - but a couple of options are:

1. If you know all the types of addresses there can be then add multiple address fk fields to the person e.g. billing address, shipping address, etc. This makes querying quick and simple but is inflexible: adding a new address type in the future is relatively complex to implement
2. Add an intersection table with fks for person and address and an address type field. This has a slight overhead when it comes to querying but has the advantage if being very flexible: adding a new address type is trivial